# Hanging GPG commands

Tags: gnupg

I am unable to commit using the `git commit` command (The console just hangs). Using the `GIT_TRACE` command I have found that it is handing on:
`run-command.c:655    trace: run_command: gpg --status-fd=2 -bsau GPGKEY`.
This has suddenly started happening (gpg has been working fine for months)

I can also not run `gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long` as this also hangs.
So it appears to be a GPG issue.

The key:

- has not expired
- is the correct one

I am able to run `gpg --version` which returns is 2.4.3

I have reinstalled gpg and restarted the computer.

Any other solutions people know of? Thanks

Using Mac on Ventura 13.4

Answer (score 0):

Got this working by uninstalling `gpg` and installing `gpg suite` instead and doing everything through that instead.

Comment: Thanks man. My gpg suddently error as well lately. My solution is to reinstall the gpg. Do you know the root cause?